# Navigate between several ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView that represents a list of folders and when I click one item, I want to load another list that shows the content of this folder. How can I link these views together and to be able to go back to the first one with the back button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you didn't provide a code in your question, I will try giving an answer in a descriptive manner.

You can use fragments to do this. Your base Activity's layout must have a fragment container which you will use to display your fragment containing the first ListView data. Once after you click on a cell, you call the constructor of the second ListView, and replace the current content of the fragment container with the newly created fragment.

You may implement a back feature by implementing an ArrayList in your Activity and appending the fragments into that array list as the user navigates through the list. onBack pressed you can call the top most fragment from that Array list and assign it to the fragment container.

This should work well, given there are not too many types of ListViews that you may want to implement.

Comment: You are right, I looked for a general explanation, not necessarily code. Your answer is perfect in that sense, thanks!